# Cannot use WSO2 ESB and AS simultaneously even after changing offset

Tags: wso2-as, wso2-esb

I extracted ESB and AS, and opened up the repository/conf/carbon.xml file of the ESB >> “Ports” configuration. Change the “Offset” setting from 0 to 1.

I can run both of them on different ports 9443 & 9444. When I try to login to both of them, either of them will get log out.

Example- First I login to AS, then when I login to ESB, AS will logout and vise-verse.
What should I do?

Comment: Did you verify that it was not the default time-out?

Comment: Yes I did, I do not think that is the issue.

Comment: Can you please also check with a different Offset then? may be 2. As I remember, I did a similar kind of work over 9443 & 9445.

Comment: I have tried it, it does not work. Kindly help me out.

Comment: I am @ work now. I will have a look and let you know, soon as time permits.

Comment: BTW, can you please tell the versions you have used?

Comment: All latest versions. Similar issue with Identity Server 5.1.0 & API Manager 1.10.0

Comment: Assuming you have a general problem of hosting two WSO2 products simultaneously, Can you please try this guide, https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics  until I try out.
This one explains to co-host WSO2 APIM & BAM, with some other configuration to co-work. You can extract out only what you want.

Comment: Yeah I have already enabled this in API Manager.

Comment: Ok. got it. I'll try your case.

Comment: Hi, did you find anything.

Comment: I replicated your problem but unluckily didn't find an answer. I'll reply soon I found one.

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a bug with products and reported an jira [1].

As a workaround, you can start two servers in two browsers. Then those instances will not automatically log out.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/WSAS-2249